# Haskell Non-exhaustive patterns in function error in Maybe?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, option-type

I am writing a function that takes a list of Dates and evaluates to an (Int, Int, Int).  If the list is empty is evaluates to Nothing and evaluates to Just d where d is the oldest Date in the list.  My Date data structure is below:

```
data Date = Date Int Int Int
 deriving (Show)
```

Here is a helper function that I use to determine if a Date is older:

```
isOlder2 :: Date -> Maybe Date -> Bool
isOlder2 (Date x y z) (Just (Date a b c))
  | x < a = True
  | x > a = False
  | (x == a)&&(y < b) = True
  | (x == a)&&(y > b) = False
  | (x == a) && (y ==b) &&(z < c) =True
  | (x == a) && (y ==b) &&(z > c) = False
  | (x == a) && (y ==b) &&(z == c) = False
```

and my actual method, oldest, is the following:

```
oldest :: [Date] -> Maybe Date 
oldest [] = Nothing
oldest (x : xs)
  | isOlder2 x oldestTail = Just x
  | otherwise = oldestTail 
    where oldestTail = oldest xs
```

I think that the issue is somewhere in the Maybe, but I'm not familiar with the structure and how it works.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `Date` is isomorphic to a tuple, which already knows how to perform the type of lexicographic comparison you want: `isOlder2 (Date x y z) (Just (Date a b c)) = (x, y, z) < (a, b, c)`.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to define `isOlder2`; `data Date = Date Int Int Int deriving (Eq, Ord)` will allow you to write `Date 1 2 3 < Date 4 5 6`, for example.

Comment: The signature `Date -> Maybe Date -> Bool` is strange.  What is the significance of using `Maybe`  for the second argument?  Why not just `Date -> Date -> Bool` ?

Answer (score 5):

And what should happen when the second argument here is `Nothing`?:

```
isOlder2 :: Date -> Maybe Date -> Bool
isOlder2 (Date x y z) (Just (Date a b c)) = ...
```

Asking ghci to tell us about the `Maybe` type:

```
*Main> :info Maybe
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

This tells us that a value of type `Maybe Date` can be either `Nothing` or `Just (Date ...)`.  So you need to add another equation to handle the `Nothing` case:

```
isOlder2 (Date x y z) Nothing = ...
```